# How to pull data depending on the user that is logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a fully functioning login/ sign up system. Now I am trying to create a user home page. On the page I want to display the users info like username. I have no idea where to start. I am using mySQL, PHP, and HTML.

Comment: SO isn't a discussion forum, so this really doesn't fit the format.  You say you don't know where to start but you must have some idea if you have a fully functioning login system.  How did you get that far?  There are plenty of classes, books, and tutorials out there for web development.

Comment: Take a look https://clevertechie.com/php/20/login-system-php-mysql-database

Answer (score -1):

You write a function in your class file where you take all information of a user to get displayed on user's home page . Call the function from the home page and catch the values in an array . Now you can use that array to display the values on the home page . Send me the table details of user and I can help you in writing the function .

Comment: What pieces of info do you need about it?

Comment: The table where you are storing the user's data and the coding structure you are using .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean like the type of code i'm using, or the name of the database. This is the whole project: https://github.com/Zachary99/Signup-login001 (I put a link because there are 7 files)

Comment: what is the name of the project ? Signup-login ?

Comment: Send me your database , I have checked the files , there is nothing written in the files . Did you write any code so far ?

Comment: Send me the database.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wBB4doXQH6z8axVfxtnmFVddRBK9kER9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you written the login section and the session variables ?

Comment: I don't think so. Did you try and look in the git hub code but it just didn't show up?

Comment: I have downloaded it and haven't find any login code there

Comment: Don't download it. Just view it in github.

Comment: You have to first write the login system and set the sessions properly , then next step will be the dashboard where you can call the important information based on the session and display it on the page .

Comment: I have created the session veriables `$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;` now how would i display that in html. so far I have `echo '<a href="userHome.php"><?php $_SESSION["uid"];?></a>
         <form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
          <button type="submit" name="submit">Logout</button>
         </form>';` This should show a button that says the user username with a link to the home page.

Comment: how would i do it then

Comment: You have to create a member page to display all information about the logged in user . And for logout create a page where you unset all sessions and re-direct to login page . Create a button in the header named logout and link to logout page .

Comment: That piece of code is a link to navigate to the user home page. I can figure it out if you would just show me how to display the session variables.